# Use select statement as input for stored procedure. T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem;

I currently have a stored procedure and when I enter 4 different parameters is does a lot of calculations and then a select statement to output the results (11 columns) like this:

[image: usp]

The starting of this query looks like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [AGG].[usp_CalculateIsentropeEfficiency] 
(
    @InlaatdrukE INT,
    @InlaattempC INT,
    @UitlaatdrukE INT,
    @UitlaattempC INT
)
AS



/*-------------------------- Omrekenen van druk naar absolute druk en temperatuur naar de eenheid Kelvin. --------------------------*/
DECLARE @InlaatdrukA DECIMAL(20,15)
DECLARE @InlaattempK DECIMAL(20,15)
DECLARE @UitlaatdrukA DECIMAL(20,15)
DECLARE @UitlaattempK DECIMAL(20,15)

SET @InlaatdrukA = @InlaatdrukE + 1.01325
SET @InlaattempK = @InlaattempC + 273.15
SET @uitlaatdrukA = @UitlaatdrukE + 1.01325
SET @UitlaattempK = @UitlaattempC + 273.15
```

After this part, I declare and set a couple more variables. Some looking up values in a lookup table and some just plain calculations.

The idea now is that these different parameters should be filled according to another select statement I did with a pivot.

The output of this pivot table looks like this:

[image: pivottable]

Where `PI,PU,TI` and `TU` are the inputs for the stored procedure.

My issue is I can't run the stored procedure for each and every row, so I was thinking to put the Pivot Select in the stored procedure to create a bigger table. This also doesn't work as I cant use the pivot table as input for variables where I do calculations with.

The desired output needs to be pivot table + calculations. like this:

`TimeKey Component PI PU TI TU Q Row# InlaatdrukA InlaattempK Tuit_s`, etc.

I hope anyone of you knows how to do this best, as I believe a stored procedure may not be the best option.

Thank you for sharing your expertise.

As asked in the comments here is more SQL code with the logic:
In the procedure:

```
--Inlaat
DECLARE @Lookup_inlaat_templower INT
DECLARE @Lookup_inlaat_druklower INT
DECLARE @Lookup_inlaat_temphigher INT
DECLARE @Lookup_inlaat_drukhigher INT

SET @Lookup_inlaat_templower = (SELECT MAX(ref.Temperature) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature <= @InlaattempK)
SET @Lookup_inlaat_druklower = (SELECT MAX(ref.Pressure) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Pressure <= @InlaatdrukA)
SET @Lookup_inlaat_temphigher = (SELECT MIN(ref.Temperature) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature >= @InlaattempK)
SET @Lookup_inlaat_drukhigher = (SELECT MIN(ref.Pressure) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Pressure >= @InlaatdrukA)

--Uitlaat
DECLARE @Lookup_uitlaat_templower INT
DECLARE @Lookup_uitlaat_druklower INT
DECLARE @Lookup_uitlaat_temphigher INT
DECLARE @Lookup_uitlaat_drukhigher INT

SET @Lookup_uitlaat_templower = (SELECT MAX(ref.Temperature) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature <= @uitlaattempK)
SET @Lookup_uitlaat_druklower = (SELECT MAX(ref.Pressure) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Pressure <= @uitlaatdrukA)
SET @Lookup_uitlaat_temphigher = (SELECT MIN(ref.Temperature) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature >= @uitlaattempK)
SET @Lookup_uitlaat_drukhigher = (SELECT MIN(ref.Pressure) FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Pressure >= @uitlaatdrukA)

/*-------------------------- Interpolatie van de gemeten inlaat temperatuur en druk. --------------------------*/
DECLARE @Isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_lowerdruk DECIMAL(19,17)
DECLARE @Isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_higherdruk DECIMAL(19,17)
DECLARE @Isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_lowerdruk DECIMAL(19,17)
DECLARE @Isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_higherdruk DECIMAL(19,17)

SET @Isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_lowerdruk = (SELECT ref.IsentropeCoefficient FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature = @lookup_inlaat_templower AND ref.Pressure = @lookup_inlaat_druklower)
SET @Isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_higherdruk = (SELECT ref.IsentropeCoefficient FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature = @lookup_inlaat_templower AND ref.Pressure = @lookup_inlaat_drukhigher)
SET @Isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_lowerdruk = (SELECT ref.IsentropeCoefficient FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature = @lookup_inlaat_temphigher AND ref.Pressure = @lookup_inlaat_druklower)
SET @Isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_higherdruk = (SELECT ref.IsentropeCoefficient FROM AGG.tblRefIsentropeEfficiency ref WHERE ref.Temperature = @lookup_inlaat_temphigher AND ref.Pressure = @lookup_inlaat_drukhigher)

DECLARE @IsentropeInlaatG1 DECIMAL(19,17)
DECLARE @IsentropeInlaatG2 DECIMAL(19,17)

SET @IsentropeInlaatG1 = ((@lookup_inlaat_druklower + @Deltax - @InlaatdrukA) * @Isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_lowerdruk + (@InlaatdrukA - @lookup_inlaat_druklower) * @isentrope_inlaat_lowertemp_higherdruk) / @deltax
SET @IsentropeInlaatG2 = ((@lookup_inlaat_druklower + @Deltax - @InlaatdrukA) * @Isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_lowerdruk + (@InlaatdrukA - @lookup_inlaat_druklower) * @isentrope_inlaat_highertemp_higherdruk) / @deltax
```

It is just setting of variables and doing calculations with them. (this is still not everything but should give more insight in how i calculate the fields. The ending of the stored procedure atm is just:

```
SELECT  InlaatdrukA = @InlaatdrukA, 
        InlaattempK = @InlaattempK, 
        UitlaatdrukA = @UitlaatdrukA, 
        UitlaattempK = @UitlaattempK,
        Interpolate_BL = @InlaatInterpolate_BL,
        Tuit_s = @Tuit_s,
        H1_Interpolate_BL = @H1_Interpolate_BL,
        H2_Interpolate_BL = @H2_Interpolate_BL,
        H2s_Interpolate_BL = @H2s_Interpolate_BL,
        IsentropeEfficiency = @IsentropeEfficiency,
        IsentropeInefficiency = @IsentropeInefficiency
```

And the entire Pivot SQL query is this:

```
with  cte_src as (    
SELECT  
VH.Value,    
VH.TimeKey,   
RIGHT(M.MeasurementOriginalName, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(M.MeasurementOriginalName))-1) AS Type,      
SUBSTRING(M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, 1))+1)+1)+1,charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, 1))+1)+1)+1) - charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, charindex('.', M.MeasurementOriginalName, 1))+1)+1)-1)  as Component         

FROM [MSTR].[tblDimMeasurement] M      
INNER JOIN [AGG].[tblTmpFactMeasurementAnalogueValueHour] VH ON VH.MeasurementKey = M.MeasurementKey        

WHERE M.MeasurementOriginalName LIKE ('%A-414-C014%') 
and RIGHT(M.MeasurementOriginalName,2) IN ('PU','PI','TI','TU','.Q')           ),

cte_piv as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeKey) as Row# from cte_src  
PIVOT(  MAX(Value)  FOR TYPE IN ([PI],[PU],[TI],[TU],[Q])  )Pivotname  

)


Select * from cte_piv
```

here i select the fields i need and with charindex i make sure i get the right part of the string.

Then pivot it so i get the outcome with `PI, PU` etc as shown above.

Comment: **Consumable** sample data and expected results, and the logic behind the calculations will help us help you. you don't actually give us any of the SQL that does the logic here, or give us any data to work with; making to impossible to us to answer at the moment I'm afraid.

Comment: Use a table-valued Parameter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I got it working when i made the Pivot inside the stored procedure. Then used temp tables and filled them row for row. Then selected the temp table :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working when i made the Pivot inside the stored procedure. Then used temp tables and filled them row for row. Then selected the temp table :)